# xAct: How to identify and split module dummy indices?

Tags: xact, indexed-variable

Hi I'm using the package xAct but I'm running into an issue. It seems that before using `//ChristoffelToGradMetric` the christoffel connection has indices (which can be printed using `FindIndices`), but after using `//ChristoffelToGradMetric` the resulting expression is no longer recognized by mathematica as having indices. I have to use `//ChristoffelToGradMetric` because I need the explicit expressions in terms of the metric (I don't want to do this by hand), then I want to replace the dummy indices in this expression with `TraceDummy`. However, mathematica does not recognize `ChristoffelCD[c,-a,-b]//ChristoffelToGradMetric` as an object with indices, so I can't split the dummy indices and this is where I need your help.

Consider a manifold with a metric:

```
<< xAct`xTensor`
DefManifold[M, D, IndexRange[a, f]]
DefMetric[-1, G[-a, -b], CD]
```

Now I want to obtain the Christoffel connection in terms of the metric. To my knowledge the only way to do this is using `//ChristoffelToGradMetric`. However, it seems that this function makes mathematica forget the indices of `ChristoffelCD[c,-a,-b]`. Before using `//ChristoffelToGradMetric` we have,

```
ChristoffelCD[c, -a, -b]
FindIndices[ChristoffelCD[c, -a -b]]
```

with the output:

$\Gamma^c_{ab}$

```
IndexList[c, -a - b]
```

Now when I use `//ChristoffelToGradMetric` and then `FindIndices` I get an empty list, so mathematica does not recognize the indices on the connection:

```
ChristoffelCD[c, -a, -b] // ChristoffelToGradMetric
FindIndices[ChristoffelCD[c,-a,-b]//ChristoffelToGradMetric]
```

with the following output:

$\frac{1}{2}  G^{c f$2982}  (\partial_aG_{b f$2982} + \partial_bG_{af$2982} - \partial_{f$2982}G_{ab})$

```
IndexList[]
```

I expected `FindIndices` would return `IndexList[c, -a, -b, f$2982, -f$2982]`, but it doesn't. If I plug the connection in terms of the metric in `FindIndices` by hand then it does work:

```
FindIndices[1/2 *G[c, f] *(PD[-a][G[-b, -f]] + PD[-b][G[-a, -f]] - PD[-f][G[-a, -b]])]
```

output:

```
IndexList[c, f, -b, -f, a]
```

What is going on here? It is crucial for my code that mathematica recognizes the indices `f$2982` as dummy indices because I want to use `TraceDummy` to split the `f`-contractions in two sums over two internal manifolds with indices `(a1, b1, ...)` and `(a2, b2, ...)`. So I want to do the following:

```
TraceDummy[ChristoffelCD[c,-a,-b]//ChristoffelToGradMetric, f$2982 -> IndexList[a1, a2]]
```

which then should replace the terms involving the dummy indices `f$2982` by two terms with sums over `a1` and `a2`, e.g. for one of the three terms:

$G^{cf}\partial_fG_{ab} = G^{ca1}\partial_{a1}G_{ab} + G^{ca2}\partial_{a2}G_{ab}$

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that FindIndices has attribute HoldFirst, and therefore by default it does not evaluate its first argument:

```
In[10]:= Attributes[FindIndices]
Out[10]= {HoldFirst, Protected}
```

To force evaluation in the first argument use Evaluate:

```
In[11]:= FindIndices[Evaluate[ChristoffelCD[c, -a, -b] // ChristoffelToGradMetric]]
Out[11]= xAct`xTensor`IndexList[c, f$30383, -b, -f$30383, -a]
```

I recommend to use IndicesOf instead of FindIndices. It is a more powerful function and does evaluate its arguments. Take for example:

```
In[12]:= expr = ChristoffelCD[c, -a, -b] // ChristoffelToGradMetric
```

Then you can compute

```
In[14]:= IndicesOf[][expr]
Out[14]= xAct`xTensor`IndexList[c, f$30389, -b, -f$30389, -a]

In[15]:= IndicesOf[Free][expr]
Out[15]= xAct`xTensor`IndexList[-a, -b, c]

In[16]:= IndicesOf[Dummy][expr]
Out[16]= xAct`xTensor`IndexList[-f$30389, f$30389]

In[18]:= IndicesOf[Up][expr]
Out[18]= xAct`xTensor`IndexList[c, f$30389]

In[19]:= IndicesOf[Down][expr]
Out[19]= xAct`xTensor`IndexList[-b, -f$30389, -a]
```

or mixtures like

```
In[20]:= IndicesOf[Free, Down][expr]
Out[20]= xAct`xTensor`IndexList[-a, -b]
```